# QComboBox: change one option of stylesheet

Tags: qt, user-interface, quartz-graphics

I have some particular `QComboBox` like this (osx style):

[image]

that I want to highlight programmatically. I used

```
combo->setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow");
```

and the background get changed, but then the whole style of my widget becomes *ugly* like this:

[image]

as you can see, the background is ok, but dropdown button got changed with '90 motif style (old good days...)

Is it possible to *just* change the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the stylesheet rules will trigger a fallback to the Windows style, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36096033/1005419).

One option to style the background is by using [QProxyStyle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html).

[Changing the palette](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Change_the_Background_Color_of_QWidget) might also work.